# In Views how do you edit Styles

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal 7 and I just installed views. I have a view all set up with a text field and an image.

This view would be used as a Welcome paragraph to my site. It will also have a picture of a map off to the right side of the paragraph.

I have it all working but the image just shows up under the text I am currently using the unformatted list option. If I use the inline option then it looks weird because the image makes a huge white space between the first and second line of the text.

I don't want to use the table option because I don't like the whole look of a table.

I noticed the Style Settings when I was editing the Image Field. and I saw you could wrap the image in a `<div>` and give that `<div>` a style class. So I added a class called MyStyle. But I have no clue as to where I am suppose to put the CSS to create that class.

I saw a post that said I would need to add it to my theme. So I went into the bartik.info and added a new css file to it. And in that CSS file I added and defined my class. But it doesnt seem to affect anything.

How do I make this work?

Comment: What you've done is what should be done....but perhaps without the ever present 'Flush caches' after adding the css stylesheet to your theme's .info file.  Without doing so, drupal won't notice your edit of the file.

Comment: http://adaptivethemes.com/how-to-add-css-files-in-drupal-7